# arm navigation 6dof

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I created moveit package and wrote drivers for my 6 dof manipulator and I also can control manipulator with moveit. I also created joint trajectory action server for moveit and simulation of robot in Gazebo. But I dont like idea that  I have to plan the path and than execute. I would like to use or create teleoperation control of my robotic manipulator with joystick "real-time". So it would follow the axes X Y Z and maybe do some basic rotations around point. Can you help me how to realize that and maybe give me som hints ?

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228862/arm-navigation-6dof/) by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2016-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your application needs a point-by-point control over the path rather than automated navigation between start and destination poses like MoveIt! does, you may use other tools. [Descartes](http://wiki.ros.org/descartes) is good for that purpose.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2016-03-12**:
Thank you for your advice. It looks good and I will try to use that package

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-03-14**:
I'm also interested in this. But on that page is says "Similar to MoveIt, but different than other planners, Descartes is primarily focused on offline or sense/plan/act applications. Real-time planning is not a feature of Descartes." That sounds like it isn't able to do what Chickenman is asking.

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2016-03-15**:
yeah I read it too and I can use it for better trajectory planning but I am still looking for something for "real time" applications

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-03-15**:
Yeah, I wonder what that text is referring to when it says "other planners". If you find anything let me know, I'll do the same.